# Loading ajax app with jsdom

Tags: ajax, node.js, backbone.js, jsdom

I'm looking for a solution to bootstrap a client side app (written in Backbone.js) on the server, so that I can serve correct content to crawlers and non-js consumers.

I've been playing around with jsdom & nodejs in an attempt to bootstrap the app, and can get it as far as loading in the basic template content, but the app appears to never start.

I've tried 2 different solutions to make sure that I have all the dependencies necessary and the app is loading correctly:

1. I tried using jsdom.env() with all the scripts usually included inline.
2. I tried using jsdom.jsdom() and making sure that FetchExternalResources, ProcessExternalResources, and MutationEvents were all correct and on.

Neither seem to fire the window.onload event though. I'm wondering if jsdom possibly doesn't fire this, or maybe calls it's callback after it would have normally been fired?

Is this a task that is possible in jsdom?

Comment: hi Jesse, this is exactly what i've been wanting to do as well. Check out this project on github for an example https://github.com/Morriz/backbone-everywhere. He's adapted Backbone.Sync to use redis, unfortunately when I tried using the normal 'ajaxy' Backbone.Sync, there is a compatibility issue with jsdom and jQuery.ajax functions. for example when calling collection.fetch() see http://groups.google.com/group/jsdom/browse_thread/thread/135458c46279deb?hl=en

Comment: I ran into the same issue using jQuery ajax functions on the server side - obviously standard XMLHTTPRequests won't work, but I found that if I overloaded the XMLHTTPRequest method inside node with one made to use the server side requests, everything works fine. Here's a blog post: http://thedanexperiment.com/2009/10/04/emulating-xmlhttprequest-in-node-js/ and a github repo: https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest. Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Jesse, im not aware of the method I have to override in node? Could you post a gist or something of your method to solve this using the library you pointed to. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yeah, it's actually super simple - first require the library: `XMLHttpRequest = require('./XMLHttpRequest.js').XMLHttpRequest;`
then inside of the `jsdom.env()` callback (or anywhere you have access to the `window` object), override it like this: `window.XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest;` - I can put more complete code in a gist if that's not clear :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't wait for window.onload as jsdom doesn't fetch images/css (yet).  When using jsdom.env, you can simply treat the callback as a "hey everything is ready now" event.

If your app relies on window.onload, you can trigger it inside the aforementioned callback.

Comment: I think that was the issue - I tried doing it that way and it failed, but the failure was in some application code. Thanks!