# jsdom: how to process scripts on the page

Tags: node.js, jsdom

Can't get jsdome execute scripts on the page:

I've got a script on the page that changes document title

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.defaultDocumentFeatures = {
      FetchExternalResources   : ['script'],
      ProcessExternalResources : true

};

...

jsdom.env({
              html: "http://localhost:3000/page"
            }, function (err, window) {
               //Check window.document.title

}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7086858/loading-ajax-app-with-jsdom

Comment: Thanks, I've read the post, But I didn't get what to do =(